# How can I Encrypt and Decry-pt Video playing any Video Player?

Tags: android, encryption, android-video-player

I working on media application, On app user able to watch video on any video player. all media file is stored in `Internal Storage` which is .mp4 formate in particular folder called `LearningVideo`.

My question is I want to encrypt that video so a user won't able access that and also decrypt that video when app play that.

So how can I achieve this task, please help me.

I tried `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use [CipherOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html?hl=es) and [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) for encryption and decryption of file in android.

There are two ways through which you can achieve your goal

Download a file and encrypt it, when you want to play that file decrypt it in a temporary file and play it.

if you want to play the encrypted file on the fly (not decrypting it in a temp file) then you can use [Libmedia](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net/) library. It streams encrypted file on localhost and plays it from there

Answer (score 0):

Try to write Files inside FilesDir may be this solved your issue

```
File rootpath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
                File path = new File(rootpath.getAbsolutePath() + "/LearningVideo");
```

You can store your files inside `/data/user/0/<packageName>/files`